# Get the links from a website URL

Tags: c#, html, web, hyperlink

Exactly what I'm trying to achieve is to get the links from [this address](https://www.flickr.com/photos/visualechos/sets/72157622467976256), the links for each individual wallpaper. For example, this link: https://www.flickr.com/photos/visualechos/14925188846/in/album-72157622467976256/.

This is some of the things I've tried, but all of the wallpaper links are not there using these methods for some reason:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string code = client.DownloadString("http://www.flickr.com/photos/visualechos/sets/72157622467976256");
}
```

-

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.flickr.com/photos/visualechos/sets/72157622467976256", @"C:\code.html");
}
```

-

```
// Using HtmlAgilityPack
public void GetLinks(string url)
    {
        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(url);
        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            LINK.Add(link.GetAttributeValue("href", "link not found"));
        }
    }


private void btnStoreLinks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetLinks("https://www.flickr.com/photos/visualechos/sets/72157622467976256");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scraping the site, you can try the flickr-API, which is documented here: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

You should read this topic on their website too: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html

After that it's rather simple, you make your first OAuth-Request for a new client secret - then you send the requests to the API. [`WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) is the library you're searching for.

Comment: I read the links, but it looks complicated... I'm not especially good at this kind of things I'm afraid, sorry. Am I supposed to include OAuth as a reference? Or how do I start?